# Read property of class returned from factory method: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Book>'

Tags: flutter, dart

how to read getter variable when it is returned from factory method? I have a class names Book like this

```
class Book {
  final String _name;
  String get name => _name;

  Program(this._name);

  factory Program.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    return Program(
      json[0]['book_name'],
    );
  }
}
```

}
and I'm fetchings book from api like this

```
Future<Book> fetchBook() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('http://book.com');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Book.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load book');
    }
  }
```

and I'm calling this method like this

```
book = fetchBook();
print(book.name)
```

but getting this error

```
The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Book>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'name', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'.
```

How get name of the book?

Comment: see https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: Change to: `book = await fetchBook();
print(book.name)`

Comment: @MidhunMP thank you, beginner mistakes :)

Comment: @tasqyn No worries. Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: @nvoigt yes it does